# Amazon SP API - How to get billing address of an order

Tags: e-commerce, amazon-selling-partner-api

I need to get the customer billing address for orders for tax purposes. Surprisingly I cannot find any way to get this information in the docs. The Orders API only gives shipping address
The only place where I have seen it mentioned is the Invoice Data Report: https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/invoice-data-reports-attributes

I cannot find any examples of this report or even test it since there is no sandbox. But because it is a report it is very tedious to get it in a reasonable way. I would have to schedule the report every 30 minutes, save all data and later when creating the order find the same order. I'm not even sure it will give me what I need.

Is there any other way to get billing address that I am missing? How do others in the EU deal with this?